# How to get values from a Messaging.Email object

Tags: email, apex-email-service

I have code which builds a list of Messaging.Email objects to be sent out based on various conditions. The problem is I want to be able to write a test which asserts that these email factory methods I've written are properly populating the fields (e.g. bccAddresses, toAddresses, etc). What I'm getting back is:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[
  getBccAddresses=(support@widgets.com);
  getCcAddresses=null;
  getCharset=null;
  getDocumentAttachments=null;
  getFileAttachments=null;
  getHtmlBody=null;
  getInReplyTo=null;
  getPlainTextBody=Test;
  getReferences=null;
  getTargetObjectId=null;
  getTemplateId=null;
  getToAddresses=(jim);
  getWhatId=null;
  isUserMail=false;
]
```

However, when I try to get one of these values I receive the following error:

```
Messaging.Email[] result = buildEmailList(testViolationList);
System.debug(result[0].getBccAddresses());
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.Email].getBccAddresses()
```

To give more context, what I am doing is generating a list Case objects which have violated our SLA in some way (violationList). buildEmailList() takes in this violation list and builds emails to people who should be notified for each level of SLA violation. I would just like to confirm in my tests that the proper email addresses are being included within the correct fields of the email objects that are returned.

Am I missing something here or are there simply no getters defined for Messaging.Email objects? There doesn't appear to be according to any of the [Apex documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.salesforce.com%2Fus%2Fdeveloper%2Fdocs%2Fapexcode%2FContent%2Fapex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm&ei=-7wwUtizKYWXiQLwkoGADw&usg=AFQjCNE7k9ERxW0UWFP1E1UwLUrf_PFfqA&sig2=MXI6otDvtjHVDfm6Kizyzg&bvm=bv.52109249,d.cGE) for Messaging objects. If that's the case is there any other way I can test the contents of this object?

**UPDATE: Hack/Solution**
As a work around I've come up with the method below. However, it seems quite hacky.

```
Messaging.Email[] result = buildEmailList(testViolationList);
String email = JSON.serialize(result[0]);
Map<String, Object> emailContents = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(email);
System.debug(emailContents.get('bccAddresses'));
```

Can anyone confirm that there is no better way to do this?

Comment: Could you please post the code that you have written in your test class and apex class so someone could help? At this moment, I am unaware what 'result' is? Is that the instance of the Apex Class?

Comment: result is a Messaing.Email[] which contains a list of email objects coming back from the email factory. I'll update the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured this one out. If you need to build a list of email objects to send out, they need to be stored within a Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[].

The [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm) for Messaging.sendEmail() states that it takes in a Messaging.Email[] as it's first argument. Since this is the case I wrote my email factory method to return a Messaging.Email[] containing all of the Messaging.SingleEmailMessage that it has generated.

The problem is that once a Messaging.SingleEmailMessage object is added to a Messaging.Email[], you can no longer use the getter methods which are available for the object. However, the getter methods are still accessible if you add each email object to a Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]. It's not listed in the documentation but I've found that Messaging.sendEmail() will also accept a Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[].

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailmessage();
email.setToAddresses(new String[] {'jasonsims87@gmail.com'});
email.setPlainTextBody('test body');
email.setSubject('test');

Messaging.Email[] emailList = new Messaging.Email[] {email};
Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);               // < Will send successfully.
System.debug(emailList[0].getToAddresses());  // < but getter method will fail.

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] emailList = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email};
Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);               // < Will also send successfully.
System.debug(emailList[0].getToAddresses());  // < And getter method succeeds.
```

Comment: Messaging.SingleEmailMessage is a subclass of Messaging.Email, and the majority of the methods on SingleEmailMessage don't exist on it's (seemingly abstract) parent type.