# What are all the public methods for Messaging.SingleEmailMessage

Tags: email, reflection

I am wrote a wrapper class that builds Messaging.Email instances but need to test that the Messaging.Email object is built properly. The published API at

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm

has only setter methods but there are some getter methods:

[How to get values from a Messaging.Email object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16563/how-to-get-values-from-a-messaging-email-object)

Where can I find the documentation for ALL the public methods that are provided by the Messaging.Email classes? Or for any class supplied by Salseforce for that matter. Or is there a way to access an instance at runtime and print its methods?

Comment: I am not really sure i understand your question, What actually you are looking for?? Any example to implement single message??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to at least see what is available is to use the Developer console autocomplete feature:
[image]

Comment: Excellent, I develop with the Force.com IDE and was not aware of the autocomplete of the Developer Console.